# Limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x \ln x+2x\ln \sin \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \right)$

Tags: limits

I think that this limit should be not defined

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow  \infty}x \ln x+2x\ln \sin \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \right)$$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Applying log properties then it must be not define

Comment: Now: tell us what you've tried, and why you think that the limit does not exist, and that'll help us know how much you understand, so we can better help you.

Comment: When x multiply sinx1÷x^ and c tends to infinity so infinity×0 = not define

Comment: Not. Go here. It may help :http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x+lnx+%2B+2x+ln+sin(1%2F(x)%5E(1%2F2))

Comment: with L'Hospital we get $$-\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: Sir l'hopital apply when infty÷infty or 0÷0

Comment: @TheDeadLegend graph explanation good

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner can we apply I'hopital . Without infity÷infity

Comment: Good question. +1 put $x=1/t^{2}$ and the expression is $(2/t^{2})\log((\sin t)/t)$.  Now use a combination of standard limits and L'Hospital's Rule to get the answer.

Comment: I solved it applying expansion

Comment: Graph representation isn't right @The Dead legend

Answer (score 3):

Too many comments, no proposed answer so far: first ,substitute

$$y:=\frac1{\sqrt x}\;,\;\;\text{and observe that}\;\;x\to\infty\implies y\to 0\;,\;\;\text{so we get the limit}$$

$$\lim_{y\to0}\left(\frac1{y^2}\,\log\frac1{y^2}+\frac2{y^2}\,\log\sin y\right)=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{-2\log y+2\log\sin y}{y^2}\stackrel{l'H}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{-\frac2y+\frac2{\sin y}\cdot\cos y}{2y}=$$$${}$$

$$=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{-\sin y+y\cos y}{y^2\sin y}\stackrel{l'H}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{-y\sin y}{2y\sin y+y^2\cos y}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{-\sin y}{2\sin y+y\cos y}\stackrel{l'H}=$$$${}$$

$$=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{-\cos y}{3\cos y-y\sin y}=-\frac13$$

Comment: Thank u sir. But it also be sloved by expansions

Comment: @NIDHITANSH And perhaps also in other ways. The above is just one of them, and (Taylor or power series) expansions seem TO ME way messier than this. But it may be a matter of taste.

Comment: It's very good method too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without substitution,
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(x\ln x+2x\ln\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}2x\left(\ln\sqrt{x}+\ln\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}2x\ln\left(\sqrt{x}\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}2x\ln\left(\sqrt{x}\left(\frac{(1/\sqrt{x})}{1!}-\frac{(1/\sqrt{x})^3}{3!}+\frac{(1/\sqrt{x})^5}{5!}+\ldots\right)\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}2x\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{6x}+\frac{1}{120x^2}-\ldots\right)$$
$$=\frac13\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{6x}\left(1+\frac{1}{20x}-\ldots\right)\right)}{\frac{1}{6x}\left(1+\frac{1}{20x}-\ldots\right)}\cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{20x}-\ldots\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}(-1)\cdot 1$$$$=\color{blue}{-\frac13}$$